# How can I get Flot to plot many points on an x axis?

Tags: javascript, flot

I have 84 x axis points that I'm trying to graph with Flot and my data is not graphing. I've been messing with `tickSize` but that's not rendering any results. It's a mess and I'd also like to be able to adjust the xaxis legend to be legible, but my primary concern is why my data isn't appearing.

Can someone help me discern why no lines and points are appearing?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJBKp/2/) link to my javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add square brackets around data attribute as it is an array of data series, not just single array of data. In your example it would be:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], options);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JJBKp/3/

See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage for more info.

And you can make Flot graph more readable if you rotate labels. AFAIK, it is not possible out of the box yet http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=85, but there are plugins and forks that fixes it:

- http://jsfiddle.net/manishsp2008/vNSD8/
- https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor